# Size of sample and correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, regression, correlation

$X$ and $Y$'s correlation coefficient is $r=0.5$. What is the size of sample when the correlation is significant at $\alpha=0.05$ with two sided test?

Is there a more "formal" way to solve this other than using the "forking" method? In order to solve P-value for the $n$, I will I need $t$, I assume? However, I'm not even sure whether the forking method is allowed in this case since there's a condition $|t|>t_{0.975}(n-2)$ and $P<\alpha$ for the significance.

I'm supposed to find the smallest $n$ where the conditions apply.

edit: I forgot to tell that I am allowed to use Excel as well. However, the functions won't work since I either lack the value of t or n is unknown.

Comment: Do you know what your statistic ($t$) is? You have your inequality already, so try to see for which $n$ this is satisfied.

Comment: I don't have my statistic t. All I have are $r=0.5$ and $\alpha=0.05$.

Comment: Just to be clear so we're not just misunderstanding each other here, I mean the equation for the statistic, not a value of it. The equation for the statistic depends on $n$, so you can then find an $n$ satisfying your condition.

Comment: Oh yes. 

$t=\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$

However, I don't know the value for t. I tried solving n from this and I got 

$n=3t^2+2$

Answer (score 0):

For the two-sided test, when $r=0.5$ you will have significance whenever $|t|>t_{0.975}(n-2)$. So when is this true? You know that 
$$
t=\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}=\frac{\frac 1 2\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{\frac 3 4}}=\frac{\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt 3}.
$$
The question then is: for which $n$ is
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt 3}>t_{0.975}(n-2)
$$
satisfied? If you're allowed to use Excel, this should not be too much of a problem.